# SOLR Exclude category products from listing, but should be available in website

Tags: apache, solr, categories

I am using Apache SOLR in my application.
I have a scenario where i need to exclude certain category products not be displayed in Product listing and detail pages. But these products to be available in few other pages.

Any SOLR configuration can be made to achieve this. 
Please let me know !

Thank you !

Comment: what you did already? how your schema.xml looks like? what's your workflow?

Comment: how do you determine which objects to hide? what does the documents look like?